# Крашится вкладка после Ajax запроса в Google Chrome

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование

Пишу на asp.net mvc 5

Такая проблема, **бывает, но редко!!** при моих ajax запросах вылетает ошибка гугла "Опаньки" ("Aw Snap")

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?visit_id=1-636269195083261282-3576979266&p=e_awsnap_rl&rd=1

Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: 1) какой код ошибки: 404, 503 или еще какая? 2) желательно код: javascript (или вьюха) + контроллер. от себя добавлю, что сталкивался с ошибкой, если долгий запрос, но тут нужны детали. скорей всего дело в другом.

Comment: Кода ошибки нету, просто страница крашится (и по центру надпись "опаньки.." ),если f5 нажать, то все ок. Запрос осуществляю хелпером, в сообщение добавлю сейчас

Comment: Блин, ну вот почему вы самую важную информацию (о том, что это - страница "опаньки") прячете под ссылкой? Вы понимаете, что такой вопрос никто никогда не найдет в поиске?

Comment: Ну там такая фраза и ссылка которая в теме, так из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: вполне возможно, что проблема в хроме (из-за плагинов например) или антивирусе. воспроизводится ли в другом браузере? воспроизводится ли при отключенном антивирусе?

Comment: Как включить дополнительную инфу по "опаньки": http://stackoverflow.com/a/30134722/2764727

Comment: У меня нету антивируса)

Comment: тогда можно поработать с сайтом в Firefox или IE и посмотреть, будут ли ошибки. Как вариант: отключить в хроме все плагины (флеш и т.д.) и тоже поработать с сайтом.